# Prove if f is continuous at x=a, f'(a) does not necessarily exist

Tags: calculus, limits

I can come up with an example that the right-hand limit does not equal to the left-hand limit, for example: $f(x)=\begin{cases} 2 &\text{ for } x\le 0 \\ 4 & \text{ for } x\ge 0\end{cases}$. So $f(x)$ is continuous at $x=0$ , but $f'(0)$ does not exist.

But how would I prove this statement in general?

Comment: No, your $f$ is not continuous at $0.$ In fact $f(0)$ is not well defined; you have two different definitions for it.

Comment: Try with $f(x)=|x|$.

Answer (score 3):

In general, all you need is an example that there is a function that is continuous at $x = a$ but is not differentiable at $x = a$. Your example is fine except that I would adjust it as follows:"$f(x) = 4, x > 0$", and another one is: $f(x) = |x|, a = 0$.

Comment: Why is the OP's example fine? It's not continuous at $0.$

Answer (score 0):

To prove the statement, it is sufficient to find one counterexample, e.g. $f(x) = \sqrt x$ at $x=0$.